# convert NSArray to NSString contains NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to convert `NSArray` to `NSString` which contains `NSDictionary` , I can achieve this with iteration through array and append string with the last one but I think there should be some easy way to achieve this something like `componentsJoinedByString:` **Is there any**?

A sample array I've is,

> [o] {name="ABC", age = "19", package = "3.4"}
>
> [1] {name="PQR", age = "33", package = "5.0"}
>
> [2] {name="XYZ", age = "24", package = "2.2"}

What I'm doing right now is,

```
NSString *name = @"";
NSString *age = @"";
NSString *package = @"";
                 
for(NSDictionary *p in array)
{
    name = [name stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@,",[p valueForKey:@"name"]];

    age = [age stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@,",[p valueForKey:@"age"]];

    package = [package stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@,",[p valueForKey:@"package"]];
}
                 
name = [name substringToIndex:[name length] - 1];
age = [age substringToIndex:[age length] - 1];
package = [package substringToIndex:[package length] - 1];
                 
NSLog(@"%@",name);
NSLog(@"%@",age);
NSLog(@"%@",package);
```

Is there more easy way to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it simply :

Assuming you have `array` contains objects of NSDictionary.

```
NSString *name = [[array  valueForKey:@"name"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSString *age = [[array  valueForKey:@"age"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSString *package = [[array  valueForKey:@"package"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];

NSLog(@"%@",name);
NSLog(@"%@",age);
NSLog(@"%@",package);
```

Comment: always remember valueForKey is KVC, objectForKey is nsdict's. Here you are using KVC...this can return arrays, whereas objForKey returns one obj,